# prefix and postfix operators java

Tags: java, operators, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I was trying unary postfix and prefix operators in java

Here's the code

```
int a=10;
```

This line of code does not give compile time error

```
System.out.println(a+++ a +++a);
```

But this line does

```
System.out.println(a++ +++a);
```

whereas this line even doesn't

```
System.out.println(a+++ ++a);
```

I can't understand the pattern of how compiler interprets these queries.

Comment: For the curious, the given compiler error is `Invalid argument to operation ++/--` under JDK 7 and 8.

Comment: My **guess** is that `+++a` is perceived by the compiler as `++` which is ok and then comes another `+` which messes things up. You could try things like `++(+a)` or `+(++a)` if you want to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of

```
System.out.println(a++ +++a);
```

The compiler appears to be interpreting this as

```
System.out.println((a++)++ +a);
```

This doesn't work because the result of a pre/post increment/decrement expression is a *value*, not a variable. (It might also be seeing it as `a+ ++(++a)` but the outcome is the same).

Indeed, if you compile this with the Oracle compiler from command line, you get the following error:

```
UnaryOperatorTests.java:10: error: unexpected type
        System.out.println(a++ +++a);
                        ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

Which is much more indicative of what's going on when compared to the Eclipse compiler's message:

> Invalid argument to operation ++/--

That said, you can get that same error from Eclipse by trying to do:

```
System.out.println(1++);
```

Adding a space thusly:

```
System.out.println(a++ + ++a);
```

seems to remove the ambiguity that confuses the compiler, and compiles as you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

1. `System.out.println(a+++ a +++a);`

   is interpreted the same as

   `System.out.println(a++ + a++ + a);`

   It's compiled and executed as follows:

   - load `a` as the first operand; ***the first operand is now 10***
   - increment `a` (first `a++`), its value is now 11
   - load `a` as the second operand; ***the second operand is now 11*** (as it was incremented in the previous step)
   - increment `a` (second `a++`), its value is now 12
   - add the two operands `10 + 11` to get 21 which is now the result of `a++ + a++`, let's call this intermediate result `i`, which will act as the first operand of the next sum
   - load `a` as the second operand; ***the second operand is now 12***
   - add `i` (21) to `a` (12) to get **33**
2. `System.out.println(a+++ ++a);`

   is interpreted the same as

   `System.out.println(a++ + ++a);`

   - load `a` as the first operand; ***the first operand is now 10***
   - post-increment `a`, its value is now 11
   - pre-increment `a`, its value is now 12
   - load `a` as the second operand; ***the second operand is now 12***
   - add the two to obtain **22**
3. The problematic `System.out.println(a++ +++a);`

   is interpreted as

   `System.out.println((a++)++ +a);`

   which would give the same error when you call post-increment on an integer literal.